# CSS: Percent of current value

Tags: css

If an element already has a fixed property-value pair, say

```
div {
    top: X px;
}
```

is it possible to set the value to (50% of X) after initial declaration using CSS ?

Comment: Not possible with CSS (for now), but possible with preprocessors like LESS or SASS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to use JS, something like: `el.style.top = el.style.top * 1.5`.

Edit: Or if you're using something like SASS you could declare the initial value as a variable and then simply multiply that: `$initialTop = 50; div {top: $initialTop * 1.5}`

Answer (score 0):

No, percentages will be calulated from the parent element. You would need to use Javascript for that functionality.